# Cython efficient cycle 'for' for a given list instead of range(N)

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, cython

I'm coding on cython (python 2.7) and I'm dealing with 'for' cycles. As long as I use the standard `for i in range(N)`, I got a cool code: no yellow warning on the cythonized `code.html`.

When I create a list of integer (as range(N) is, isn't it?), for example:

```
cdef long [:] lista = np.array(list(nx.node_connected_component(Graph, v)))
```

which gives me the list of all indices of the nodes in the connected component of `v` in the graph `Graph`. I got a yellow warning when I try to define `for i in lista:`:

```
  __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_memoryview_fromslice(__pyx_v_lista, 1, (PyObject *(*)(char *)) __pyx_memview_get_long, (int (*)(char *, PyObject *)) __pyx_memview_set_long, 0);; if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  if (likely(PyList_CheckExact(__pyx_t_1)) || PyTuple_CheckExact(__pyx_t_1)) {
    __pyx_t_6 = __pyx_t_1; __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_6); __pyx_t_15 = 0;
    __pyx_t_17 = NULL;
  } else {
    __pyx_t_15 = -1; __pyx_t_6 = PyObject_GetIter(__pyx_t_1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_6)) __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
    __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_6);
    __pyx_t_17 = Py_TYPE(__pyx_t_6)->tp_iternext; if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_17)) __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  for (;;) {
    if (likely(!__pyx_t_17)) {
      if (likely(PyList_CheckExact(__pyx_t_6))) {
        if (__pyx_t_15 >= PyList_GET_SIZE(__pyx_t_6)) break;
        #if CYTHON_COMPILING_IN_CPYTHON
        __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_6, __pyx_t_15); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_15++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
        #else
        __pyx_t_1 = PySequence_ITEM(__pyx_t_6, __pyx_t_15); __pyx_t_15++; if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
        __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
        #endif
      } else {
        if (__pyx_t_15 >= PyTuple_GET_SIZE(__pyx_t_6)) break;
        #if CYTHON_COMPILING_IN_CPYTHON
        __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_6, __pyx_t_15); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_15++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
        #else
        __pyx_t_1 = PySequence_ITEM(__pyx_t_6, __pyx_t_15); __pyx_t_15++; if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
        __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
        #endif
      }
    } else {
      __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_t_17(__pyx_t_6);
      if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {
        PyObject* exc_type = PyErr_Occurred();
        if (exc_type) {
          if (likely(exc_type == PyExc_StopIteration || PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches(exc_type, PyExc_StopIteration))) PyErr_Clear();
          else __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
        }
        break;
      }
      __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
    }
    __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyInt_As_int(__pyx_t_1); if (unlikely((__pyx_t_2 == (int)-1) && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 151, __pyx_L1_error)
    __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
    __pyx_v_i = __pyx_t_2;
/* … */
  }
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_6); __pyx_t_6 = 0;
```

The code obviously works, but, since I need to use these cycles quite often, I would like to now how to implement them correctly.

Which is the correct assignment for `lista` ?

Comment: What does `nx.node_connected_component` return? That may determine what you have to do.

Comment: @DavidW it returns a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off just looping over it by index

```
cdef Py_ssize_t i
cdef long val
with cython.boundscheck(False): # these two lines are optional but may increase speed
  with cython.wraparound(False):
    for i in range(lista.shape[0]):
      val = lista[i]
```

Another optimization you could probably make is to define `lista` as

```
cdef long [::1] lista
```

which states that it's continuous in memory.

(My initial reading of the question made me think it was about the conversion from a `set`: `np.array(list(nx.node_connected_component(Graph, v)))`. I don't think this is what you're asking about, but in case it was, I can't see a way to speed up this line.)

Comment: I don't understand one thing. Why we define `val`? Is it important or I can just use `lista[i]`? And what is the idea behind cdef `Py_ssize_t` ? THanks

Comment: You can just use `lista[i]`. `Py_ssize_t` is an signed integer that is big enough to use for indexing into any array that Python can allocate. You can use any integer type you like, but if `lista` gets too long you might not be able to reach the end.